# Can Regex switch charactors in a string?

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have a large db of parcel ID's.  The problem with this db is
that pattern is wrong.

```
0000-22N-6W-01
should be written:
0000-01-22N-6W
```

Can Regex do a switch or do I need to look at another python procedure.

Comment: Yes, although a regular expression isn't *required*. Take the data, break it down into parts (e.g. `str.split` or with *capture groups* in a regular expression), and then build the result (e.g. with concatenation or regular expression replacement).

Comment: Use `re.sub()` to do replacement, and use capture groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace pattern `^(.{4})(.{4})(.{3})(.{3})` with `\1\4\2\3`

```
import re
input = raw_input()
output = re.sub(r'^(.{4})(.{4})(.{3})(.{3})', r'\1\4\2\3', input)
print output
```

Test it **[here](http://ideone.com/TD4i3s)**.

Comment: Would the first pattern be ^(.{4})(.{3})(.{3})(.{3})$   ? and just use re.sub like: vac_re = re.sub(r"^(.{4})(.{3})(.{3})(.{3})$",r"\1\4\3\2",vac)  I'm still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in pure Python.  Matter of taste.

```
>>> data = "0000-22N-6W-01"
>>> parts = data.split('-')
>>> parts[1:] = parts[3], parts[1], parts[2]
>>> new_data = '-'.join(parts)
>>> new_data
'0000-01-22N-6W'
```