# Regex re.sub list in a file

Tags: python, regex

I have a text list that will re.sub fine with some like: `re.sub('0000', '1111',data)`.

A replace pattern `^(.{4})(.{4})(.{3})(.{3})` with `\1\4\2\3` for one input in the shell
works fine also.  However, my attempt to use this pattern in a list gives me an
undesirable result on the first row and never replace the latters. What am I missing here?

```
"0000-22N-06W-01"
"0000-22N-06W-02"
"0000-22N-06W-03"
"0000-22N-06W-04"

import re
o = open("output.txt","w")
data = open("input.txt").read()
o.write(re.sub(r'^(.{4})(.{4})(.{3})(.{3})', r'\1\4\2\3',data))
o.close()
```

Comment: You could perhaps use [`.readline()`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) and a loop to read the file line by line instead. Also, is your regex correct? The pattern seems to ignore the hyphens.

Comment: It's correct:  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927676/can-regex-switch-charactors-in-a-string)

Comment: No it's not. The one in the link has `6W` while yours has `06W`.

Comment: @George I have modified my answer taking everything into consideration, please let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: See my answer, please. And go and upvote Jerry's answer because he says the same before me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
"0000-22N-06W-01"
"0000-22N-06W-02"
"0000-22N-06W-03"
"0000-22N-06W-04"

import re
output = open("output.txt","w")
input = open("input.txt")

for line in input:
    output.write(re.sub(r'^(.{4})-(.{3})-(.{3})-(.{2})$', r'\1-\4-\2-\3', line))

input.close()
output.close()
```

**NOTE:** If you actually have `"` in your data then you should change your regular expression to this one:

```
^"(.{4})-(.{4})-(.{3})-(.{3})"$
```

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bO1dS2)

Comment: [you lose 1 PythonPoint™ every time you use a semicolon](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/11183191#11183191)

Comment: Nice one @Jerry. I don't work with Python, I copied code from here and there, modified it a bit and then my C# habits came into the scene :).

Comment: The output should write 0000-01-22N-6W, 0000-02-22N-6W, 0000-03-22N-6W, 0000-04-22N-6W as the pattern is \1\4\2\3. I'm still getting the same input.

Comment: @George I have included a demo in my answer, check it and I will see what might be causing your issue.

Comment: @George I have just tested the code on my machine and everything is working pretty well.

Comment: Your first sample was fine.  I just need to be careful about cleaning my sample script.  My old example (still active), was still taunting me. Your the best Jerry.

Comment: @George I'm Jerry, and he's Sniffer ^^

Answer (score 4):

If you still want to use `.read()`, try this:

```
import re
output = open("output.txt","w")
input = open("input.txt").read()

output.write(re.sub(r'^(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{3})$',
                    r'\1\4\2\3', 
                    input, 
                    flags=re.M))

output.close()
```

Comment: Ahem. I should have read your answer more cmosely before writing mine, and you should make more immediately readable your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This ? :

```
import re

t = """0000-22N-06W-01
0000-22N-06W-02\t\t
0000-22N-06W-03   \t\t\t\t
0000-22N-06W-04"""
print t,'\n'

print re.sub(r'^(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})([^ \t\r\n]+)',
             r'\1\4\2\3',
             t,
             flags= re.M)
```

produces

```
0000-22N-06W-01
0000-22N-06W-02     
0000-22N-06W-03                 
0000-22N-06W-04 

0000-01-22N-06W
0000-02-22N-06W     
0000-03-22N-06W                 
0000-04-22N-06W
```

Once upon a time, it took 1 hour to me to understand that the regex expression needed to have `re.M` written after `flags=` because the signature of re.sub is `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`