# replace string with re in a file

Tags: python, regex

I want to quickly cancel out some unimportant strings in my file using the python module re.

I've tried it with other modules too, various loops and functions, but all I can get is to find the strings, not replace them with re.sub.

```py
import re

chat = open("chat.txt"
chatText = chat.read()

def deleteMetaData():
    for line in chatText:
        re.sub("\[\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d,\s\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\]\sGian\sDogwiler:\s", "", line)

deleteMetaData()
```

there are no error messages or whatsoever, just nothing. My goal is to cancel [20.07.18, 20:23:09] Gian Dogwiler: in every line of the file.

Comment: `re.sub` returns a new string. You are not using it so it does nothing

Comment: Please [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to see why you shouldn't ignore the return value of `re.sub`.

Comment: you can also simply use the string function of replacing: line.replace(old, new). See: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-replace/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`re.sub()` doesn't automatically replace data in a file - you need to write it to the file as well. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18935646/7431860) provides a great example; I've modified it slightly to match your code. Note that you're also missing a close-paren on your `chat = open("chat.txt"` line.

```py
import re

chat = open("chat.txt")
chatout = open("out.txt", "w")

def deleteMetaData():
  for line in chat:
    chatout.write(re.sub("\[\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d,\s\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\]\sGian\sDogwiler:\s", "", line))

deleteMetaData()

chat.close()
chatout.close()
```

Don't forget to `.close()` your files when you're done with them.

[Try it here!](https://repl.it/repls/FirmUnsteadyEvaluations)

Comment: Thanks, Nick Reed, it's kind of working right now, but only with one letter, i.e. "G", not with \[\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d,\s\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\]\sGian\sDogwiler:\s Edit: just found out that not every line is individually processed, but every single character.

Comment: @GDog Sounds like you might be using `chatText = chat.read` for your input - that puts each "line" in a separate character. Try reading directly from `chat` in your for loop instead. If that's not the issue, please let me know.

Comment: just using for line in chat: doesn't do anything :/

Comment: @GDog It might help if you post the updated code. Did the example I included not work for you?

Comment: Oh well, it just worked, thanks for your time :)

Comment: @GDog Very glad to help, good luck!